# 3D Model file format with just geometry

Tags: model, 3d, geometry, file-format

I am looking to find a very basic file format for a 3d model that only contains the data for the geometry of the model, no texturing or anything else, for a basic 3d rendering engine I have made in python

Comment: What kind of geometry? Only triangles/polygons or does it include curved surfaces like cylinders or splines?

Comment: I only want a format that has vertices and triangles

Comment: STL is the standard for this. There is an ASCII and a binary version. The ASCII version is probably easier to read and write but will of course produce larger files.

Comment: I wouldn't say that STL is *the* standard. It is one common format. Other common formats are [Wavefront OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), [PLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)), or [OFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format)).

Comment: STL is simple and very common it contains 3x 3D point (triangle) and normal per each face (so it still have normal above your wanted data) easy to load here [Generating outside supporters into mesh for 3D printing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555506/2521214) C++ example